# What _name_estimators does in the following code?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

```
from sklearn.pipeline import _name_estimators
class MajorityVoteClassifier(BaseEstimator,ClassifierMixin):
      def __init__(self,classifiers,vote='classlabel',weights=None):
        self.classifiers = classifiers
        self.named_classifiers={key:value for key,value in 
                                         _name_estimators(classifiers)}
        self.vote=vote
        self.weights=weights
clf1=LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=0.001,random_state=1)
clf2=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1,criterion='entropy',                                           
                                                  random_state=0)
clf3=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1,p=2,metric='minkowski')

pipe1=Pipeline([['sc',StandardScaler()],['clf',clf1]])
pipe3=Pipeline([['sc',StandardScaler()],['clf',clf3]])
mv_clf=MajorityVoteClassifier(classifiers=[pipe1,clf2,pipe3])
```

I am unable to understand how `_name_estimators` work so please can 
someone explain me what is  `_name_estimators` doing in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run this in interactive mode:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import _name_estimators

estimators = ['a', 'a', 'b' ]
_name_estimators(estimators)
# >>> [('a-1', 'a'), ('a-2', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
```

So basically it returns tuples, with unique keys. Every tuple contains the estimator + if the estimators are duplicated its occurence and the raw estimators value.

Answer (score 0):

You give the function _name_estimators a list of n estimators and it returns a list of n tuples. The first component in each tuple is a string describing the name of the estimator, and the second component of each tuple is the estimator object

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.pipeline import _name_estimators
clf = GaussianNB()
clf2 = LinearRegression()
res = _name_estimators([clf, clf2])
print(res)
print(type(res))
print()
for p in res:
    print(type(p[0]))
    print(type(p[1]))


#[('gaussiannb', GaussianNB(priors=None, var_smoothing=1e-09)), ('linearregression', LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False))]
#<class 'list'>

#<class 'str'>
#<class 'sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB'>
#<class 'str'>
#<class 'sklearn.linear_model.base.LinearRegression'>
```